# Why do you need a specific syntax to insert data into postgresql

Tags: php, string, syntax, brackets

I have found a way to insert data into a postgresql database using php. Therefore, I used the following syntax:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO genes 
        (id,gene,plasmid,accessionnumber,plasmidname) 
        VALUES ('".$var_id."','".$var_gene."','".$var_ACC."','".$var_PN."')";
```

Why do you have to use quotes within quotes and adding a point before and after the variable?

Comment: point concatenates your string, quotes you use to separate literal from variables. your question is to php, not postgres

Comment: One possible baby step would be to print the content of $sql before executing it, so that you can copy-and-paste it to your favorite tool to check it if needed. BTW, I edited your tags as suggested by @VaoTsun

Comment: Also, you need to find whoever taught you how to use databases in PHP and [demand your money back](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Did I read SQL injection or ORM here ? ;)

Comment: Is it necessary if you will run you script on a secure server?

Comment: The problem is the data, not the server. And if someone tampers with the data, you could be facing serious data loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer on the question is point concatenates your string, quotes you use to separate literal from variables. (Vao Tsun)